# Reading an excel file with read_excel

Tags: r

This is my where I got my data set from [here](http://introstat.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/1/8/31183735/jonestown.xls). 
When I fist read in the data set, and do the `head` function to double check and this is the output I get the first 7 variable shown, but then I'll get

```
Variables not shown: Status 11/18 (chr), Location 11/18 (chr), Age 11/18 (dbl), age grp (chr), Gender (chr),
  Ethnic (chr), Prev Relig Aff (chr), Adult/Minor (chr), Resident US Pre-Guyana (chr), Occup US Pre Guyana
  (chr), Govt Income (chr), JT Residence (chr), Occup in JT ~77 (chr), Occup JT ~Aug 78 (chr)
```

Here is my code

```
library(readxl)
require(mosaic)
Jonestown = read_excel("C:/Users/Deborah/Desktop/School/STA 418/Homework/jonestown.xls", sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, skip=0)
head(Jonestown)
```

Next, I need to create a data set named minors that includes only
(a) people identified as a minor
(b) who were born in the United States and
(c) has only the variables Birth State, Guyana Entry, Status 11/18, Age 11/18, Gender and Ethnic.  You should end up with 293 observations and 6 variables. This is what I have so far

```
minor = Jonestown$`Adult/Minor`=="Minor" & Jonestown$`Birth Country`=="USA"
Minors = Jonestown[minor,]
```

I am not show where to go next. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use this package instead. Works for me:

```
install.packages("xlsx")#Excel
require("xlsx")#Excel
read.xlsx("C:/Users/Deborah/Desktop/School/STA 418/Homework/jonestown.xls",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the output you first question ("Variables not shown") is perfectly normal and expected when dealing with `read_excel`. More the point, you may notice (with experimentation) that `read_excel` returns a class `tbl_df`, something from the Hadleyverse of packages that intends to provide a more intuitive/graceful presentation and handling of data.frames. It tries very hard to limit the output or "peek" at the contents of a data.frame based on the width (number of characters) of your current window. (Of course, it only does this if you have previously done `library(dplyr)`.)

Second, for filtering, since you're already using one component of the Hadleyverse, I'll suggest a second (though it is not strictly necessary here):

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    filter(`Adult/Minor` == 'Minor', `Birth Country` == 'USA') %>%
    select(`Birth State`, `Guyana Entry`)
## Source: local data frame [293 x 2]
##    Birth State Guyana Entry
##          (chr)       (time)
## 1           CA         <NA>
## 2           MI   1977-09-23
## 3           MS   1977-08-28
## 4           CA         <NA>
## 5           CA   1977-07-23
## 6           CA         <NA>
## ...
```

This is just a start, you should be able to bring in the other variables you want. I strongly recommend a `dplyr` tutorial, such as the [vignette that comes with it](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

NB: because the column names are not strictly legal (too harsh a word?) for *R* (see `?data.frame` and `?make.names`), you need to use the backtick instead of single or double quotes.